# Setting apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache2

I've followed this tutorial to try and set an apache server: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html/comment-page-1#comments

At first I got a message that I could access the server but there was nothing. When I tried the Perl example, I got an error saying that the file didn't exist. I toyed with the conf files and now can't access the server at all. When I type the address of the server I get a forbidden message.

How can I step back my changes? How can I create the cgi server?

Comment: Also, do any of you know about a tutorial for Arch Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall apache and remove previous configuration files with the following command:

```
apt-get purge apache2 apache2.2-common apache2.2-bin
```

Please use the [official and updated server guide from the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html) instead of a tutorial from 2008. The segment on web servers should get you started, but it is worth to read the whole documentation, because it covers all the things you need to know when running a server.

The ArchWiki also has an article about [Apache/LAMP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache).